# timedelta error with numpy.longdouble dtype

Tags: python, numpy, types, timedelta, python-datetime

I have times with dtype `numpy.longdouble` and when I'm trying to use that values with `timedelta` function I've got errors. But when I convert it to `numpy.float64` everything is fine. Could somebody explain that behaviour?

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta
t1 = np.array([1000], dtype=np.longdouble)
t2 = np.array([1000], dtype=np.float64)

In [166]: timedelta(seconds=t1[0])
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: numpy.float64

In [167]: timedelta(seconds=t2[0])
Out[167]: datetime.timedelta(0, 1000)

In [168]: timedelta(seconds=t1[0].astype(np.float64))
Out[168]: datetime.timedelta(0, 1000)
```

When I'm trying to see dtypes of variables they are look the similar but not the same:

```
In [172]: t1[0].dtype
Out[172]: dtype('float64')

In [173]: t2[0].dtype
Out[173]: dtype('float64')

In [174]: np.longdouble == np.float64
Out[174]: False

In [175]: t1[0].dtype == t2[0].dtype
Out[175]: True
```

## Edit

And it's strange that it's not working for np.int32 and np.int64 either:

```
t3 = np.array([1000], dtype=np.int32)
t4 = np.array([1000], dtype=np.int64)

In [29]: timedelta(t3[0])
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.int32

In [69]: timedelta(t4[0])
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.int64
```

Comment: You may have some explication [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> So maybe `timedelta` for dtype `np.longdouble` isn't implemented?

In short, yes.

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects):

> *class* `datetime.timedelta`([*days*[, *seconds*[, *microseconds*[, *milliseconds*[, *minutes*[, *hours*[, *weeks*]]]]]]])
>
> All arguments are optional and default to `0`. **Arguments may be ints, longs, or floats**, and may be positive or negative.

Here *"long"* refers to a Python `long` integer, not a `longdouble` float.

---

## Update

I think I've figured the seemingly inconsistent behavior of `np.float64`.
What seems to be relevant is whether or not the numpy dtype subclasses one of the native Python scalar types that `timedelta` accepts.

On my 64 bit machine, running Python 2.7.9, numpy v1.10.1:

```
In [1]: timedelta(np.float64(1))
Out[1]: datetime.timedelta(1)

In [2]: timedelta(np.float32(1))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4a7874ba393b> in <module>()
----> 1 timedelta(np.float32(1))

TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.float32

In [3]: timedelta(np.int64(1))
Out[3]: datetime.timedelta(1)

In [4]: timedelta(np.int32(1))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0475c6c8f1aa> in <module>()
----> 1 timedelta(np.int32(1))

TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.int32

In [5]: issubclass(np.float64, float)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: issubclass(np.float32, float)
Out[6]: False

In [7]: issubclass(np.int64, int)
Out[7]: True

In [8]: issubclass(np.int32, int)
Out[8]: False
```

However the OP reported in the comments that `timedelta(np.int64(1))` did *not* work using Python 3.4.3. I think that is due to the fact that [when numpy is built on Python 3x, `np.int64` no longer subclasses `int`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#built-in-scalar-types).

Here's what happens in Python 3.4.3:

```
In [1]: timedelta(np.int64(1))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9902ea26a52d> in <module>()
----> 1 timedelta(np.int64(1))

TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta days component: numpy.int64

In [2]: issubclass(np.int64, int)
Out[2]: False
```

Comment: that's really strange. I thought python is platform independent. Which version of numpy and python are you using? Mine: `numpy: 1.10.1;  Python 3.4.3`

Comment: Yes, it does seem to be Python3-specific behavior. See my update.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into a similar issue where

`timedelta(days = value.astype(int))` did not work but

`timedelta(days = int(value))` worked.

I hope it is useful for future Googlers.

Answer (score 1):

On Anaconda64, Win7, Python 2.7.11, NumPy 1.10.1, timedelta's response to numpy.int32 depends on the value:

```
In [3]: datetime.timedelta(seconds = numpy.int32(2147))
Out[3]: datetime.timedelta(0, 2147)

In [4]: datetime.timedelta(seconds = numpy.int32(2148))
Out[4]: datetime.timedelta(-1, 84253, 32704)
```

Full log from Spyder startup:

```
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec  7 2015, 14:10:42) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
%guiref   -> A brief reference about the graphical user interface.
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: import datetime

In [3]: datetime.timedelta(seconds = numpy.int32(2147))

Out[3]: datetime.timedelta(0, 2147)

In [4]: datetime.timedelta(seconds = numpy.int32(2148))

Out[4]: datetime.timedelta(-1, 84253, 32704)
```